# What should be the out put of Delauny Mesh Triangulation algorithm for 3-Dimension?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, mesh, delaunay

If this are the input points:

[image]

to the  [Delauny Mesh Triangulation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), then what will be output of **Delauny Mesh Triangulation algorithm** for **3-Dimension**?

**A.**  This one:

[image]

or **B.** This one [ConvexHull of all given input points]

[image]

What is your answer? **A** or **B**

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, your result B is correct, and A is a "trimmed down" version without edges longer than a certain threshold.

**But:** check out [alpha shapes](http://biogeometry.duke.edu/software/alphashapes/index.html). They generalize the concept to fit both your results! They simply become the results with different alpha values.

However, alpha shapes are mostly a theoretical concept. One of the most popular algorithms that constructs surfaces from points is [ball-pivoting](http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf), which will generate the surface of a specific alpha-shape.

Comment: how could we get  A  as my output....from input points....is there not any standard algorithm?

Comment: At least not the simple delauny triangulation, as in 3d it should be a tetrahedralization (hope I spelled it right) and you want a triangulation.

Comment: @Pritesh: Conceptually, you calculate the alpha shape for a specific alpha value and throw away the inner edges. Practically, you would use the ball-pivoting algorithm (ball radius=alpha), which does just that. To the best of my knowledge, ball-pivoting is the standard algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a surface but a "volume" made of tetrahedrons with B as surface.

Most of the faces of the tetrahedrons have to be removed to get a clean surface as in A, but for this you have to decide which tetrahedrons are inside and which are outside.

In 2D the same problem would be to get a line from the triangle mesh. What may allow to choose the right line is the density of points which aligns with the surface when data comes from some sensor. For random points there is no "good" solution.

Answer (score 2):

The output in A is obtained by *surface reconstruction from points*. There are several methods for this, many of them based on Delaunay triangulation. See for instance http://cgal.inria.fr/Reconstruction/ and http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~tamaldey/surfrecon.htm .

Answer (score 0):

The Delaunay triangulation is **equivalent to computing the convex hull** of the points

**SOURCE:** http://www.exaflop.org/docs/cgafaq/cga6.html#Subject 6.01: Where can I get source for Voronoi/Delaunay triangulation?